# Can you change PNG IDAT bits and still open and save the file?

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library

I know that this is kinda random question, but hear me out :)

Im using Python and PIL to make a script that could hide text into a PNG file.
My idea was after some research that I could take PNG file's IDAT chunks (those that have pixel bytes) and change those bytes last bits. So f.e. if one byte would be 10 (00000110) then I could change it to 9 (00000101). I would do this process to write all the bits of my message into those bytes. After that I could then read last two bits to compose the message that is hidden.

For some reason though when I am trying to save or open a file I have changed with my code I get:

`OSError: broken data stream when reading image file`

I did some tests and opening and saving normal PNG files works fine. At this point I guess the problem has to be that I can't change those bits just like I want.

Anyone have knowledge about PNG format to know what could cause this? I know that IDAT chunks have filter bytes, but I am not sure are those vital for the file to work properly.

Comment: We'd really need some code snippets to try and solve why you're getting the answer you are.  But you really can't just change random arbitrary bits.  There are built-in value checks to detect corrupted data.

Comment: The chunks are each preceded by a CRC32 checksum, so you cannot just alter the data without a reader noticing it.

Comment: Aaah, I didn't know that about those. Well that explains a lot. I have to figure out something else then. Thanks for help :)